# Is there a way to consistently keep Blazorise columns side by side?

Tags: html, css, razor, blazor, blazorise

I am noticing some inconsistencies within Blazorise column spacing.  Here I have isolated the most basic version of what I am seeing. I have taken two snippets of code from the Blazorise official website, and pasted them in the same file, right next to one another, and they result in different behavior.

I have been having a lot of difficulty getting columns to stay side by side, when when specifically defining column sizes to be smaller than the allotted 12 units of space they are allowed. The following is the code.  The top <Row> is an example of columns that have less than the max size of 12 units but still will not align. The second row is an example of a full row that does not align. The third is an example of a full line that inexplicably DOES align.

[image: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVggF.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVggF.png)]

The following is the browser result, regardless of resizing. Has anyone seen anything like this before, or know how I can fix it?  I have a lot of items in Blazorise components that simply do not align along the lines of this bug/my oversight.

[image]

I have tried putting things in and out of divs/cards/other rows, but have not yet come up with a reason that they would act any differently. Pasting more copies of the same code ABOVE the current code results in the behavior where the items do not stay on the same line, and pasting more rows BELOW results in behavior where the two columns remain on one line.

Answer (score 0):

I just have tried it with the latest version of blazorise (1.1.4.1) on a new project and it all behaves as expected.

If you are using other css files into your wwwroot/index.html make sure you comment those out for testing purposes. If they cause any conflicts commenting out those should fix your issue.

[image]

This is what my index.html looks like

inside of the head section

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css">
<link href="_content/Blazorise/blazorise.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="_content/Blazorise.Bootstrap/blazorise.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

inside of the body section

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-VHvPCCyXqtD5DqJeNxl2dtTyhF78xXNXdkwX1CZeRusQfRKp+tA7hAShOK/B/fQ2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
```

Comment: Somewhere between my fourth and seventh rebuild the issue resolved itself and I have not been able to recreate it. I guess I'll consider it closed for now, although it was very odd while it lasted.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere between my fourth and seventh rebuild the issue resolved itself and I have not been able to recreate it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).